# A false recursion

Tags: python, recursion, boolean

This is a program for checking if a number is a polindrome.
Why is it bringing me back "none" answer with str "aaaa"?

```
def is_palindrome(str):
  a=len(str)

  if str[0]!= str[a-1]:
    return False
  else:
    str=str[1:a-1]
    print str
    if str=="":
        return True
    else:
        is_palindrome(str)

is_palindrome("aaaa")
```

Comment: I don't know this language, but don't you miss a `return`?

Comment: And if you are checking index `0` and `a-1` first, shouldn’t the recursive call be made with `1` and `a-2` instead …?

Comment: The call is good, I checked it. but in the end it brings me back none instead of true, I dont know why.

Comment: @user2923032 One of the last lines say `is_palindrome(str)` and what you probably want to say is `return is_palindrome(str)`.

Comment: Please tag your questions with the programming language you are using.

Comment: @RobinGreen You can retag yourself by pressing edit and then filling out the tags field to your liking. With 7000 rep and three years of membership you should know this!

Comment: BTW, your function will not work if you pass it the string. AS a rule of thumb, you want to test your string for emptyness as the first thing and only then test the contents.

Comment: @kqr I should and do know that, but I wasn't 100% confident that it was in fact Python!

Answer (score 0):

kqr left the answer, you need to put `return is_palindrome(str)`

I know this is probably homework, but if not, why do it recursively?

```
>>> def is_palindrome(s1):
...     s1 = s1.lower().strip()
...     return s1 == s1[::-1]
...
>>> is_palindrome("racecar")
True
>>> is_palindrome("rainbow")
False
>>>
```